# Spring fails to lookup jdbc configured Data Source

Tags: spring, jndi, jta

I have deployed my application on tomcat 5.5 and the IDE is eclipse   with myeclipse plugin. when I try to start the tomcat server I get the following error:

> ERROR - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(219) | Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/xaconfig/daoJPAConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:546)
>    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
>    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
>    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
>    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3669)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4104)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1012)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:442)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:683)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:537)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409)
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
>    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:778)
>    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:161)
>    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
>    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
>    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
>    ... 27 more

I have configured the datasource in Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf as:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Environment
      name="simpleValue"
      type="java.lang.Integer"
      value="30"/>
    <Resource
      name="jdbc/Paymentsdb"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxActive="20"
      maxIdle="10"
      username="root"
      maxWait="20000"
      validationQuery="SELECT=1"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      password="root"
      url="jdbc\:mysql\://devserver\:3306/payhub"/>
    <Resource
      auth="Container"
      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      name="UserDatabase"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

and i added   Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\ context.xml page 

and  i added my webInf\web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
   <description>PaymentsDatabase</description>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/Paymentsdb</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I am using spring framework,hybernate+jpa . Please let me know, what the problem could be?

Comment: where is the spring cfg?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend putting that in the global config for Tomcat.  There's no guarantee that you'll have access to it.  Better to put it in META-INF/context.xml.

You didn't show your Spring config for the JNDI data source.  Please include that.

> nested exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   Name java:comp is not bound in this
>   Context

Shouldn't this be `java:comp/env`?